# i want to get meta data in othersite

Tags: reactjs

i'm a frontend developer.
i want to get metadata.
so i use the metascraper libraray. ==>https://www.npmjs.com/package/metascraper
it is npm libraray.

but i'm faced with an unexpected difficulty that cors error.

how can i do?
please help me.

```
Metascraper
        .scrapeUrl("http://www.naver.com")
        .then((metadata) => {
            console.log(metadata)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't control the target, the only solution is to proxy the request through your local server.

To do that, you'd create a server side script in something like PHP/Node which takes a URL and does a server-to-server request to get the response and output it. Your Metascraper would call your local server side script, passing the target URL. This would work because server-to-server calls are not subject to [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

If you did happen to control the target, then you can output a CORS header (access-control-allow-origin) to disable CORS for everyone or a whitelist of domains.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the error, that you get in console browser?

I have tried to do the same request to naver.com.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $.get('https://www.naver.com/').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
})
</script>
```

And got the next error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.naver.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access.`

So we can make a conclusion that naver.com server doesn't support CORS.
And there is no problem with library that you are trying to use.